# Rx - How to create IObservable<T> from Task<T> such that unsubscribing cancels the task?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm new to Rx so bear with me.

I want to wrap a `Task<T>` in an `IObservable<T>`. So far so good:

```
Task<T> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(...);
IObservable<T> obs = task.ToObservable();
```

Now, what I want is to signal the task to cancel when the observer unsubscribes:

```
var cancel = new CancellationToken();
Task<T> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(..., cancel);

IObservable<T> obs = task.ToObservable(); //there should be a way to tie the cancel token
                                          //to the IObservable (?)

IDisposable disposable = obs.Subscribe(...);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
disposable.Dispose(); // this should signal the task to cancel
```

How do I do that?

FWIW here's the scenario that generated this tangent: [Rx and tasks - cancel running task when new task is spawned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18477018/11545)

Comment: It might be simplest to use one of the `Observable.Create` overloads which lets you pass in a `Func<IObserver,CancellationToken,Task>`. Note, though, this would start a new Task upon subscription rather than prior to.

Comment: I think starting tasks upon subscription is actually *the right thing* in my case :)

Comment: Also, I stumbled upon the `Observable.Create()` overloads taking a cancellation token, but have yet to find a compelling example using that - could you write one (or link to one, if you know any)?

Comment: BTW: I've only met those overloads thanks to IntelliSense; the MSDN documentation [doesn't even list them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.create.aspx)

Comment: At the time you asked this question, I'm not sure whether the `Observable.FromAsync` methods existed.  These are now the correct way to do this, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest way I can think of, using `Observable.Create`:

```
static IObservable<int> SomeRxWork()
{
    return Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        IDisposable sub = SomeAsyncWork(cts.Token).ToObservable().Subscribe(o);
        return new CompositeDisposable(sub, new CancellationDisposable(cts));
    });
}

static Task<int> SomeAsyncWork(CancellationToken token);
```

The initial way I hinted at in the comments is actually rather verbose:

```
static IObservable<int> SomeRxWork()
{
    return Observable.Create<int>(async (o, token) =>
    {
        try
        {
            o.OnNext(await SomeAsyncWork(token));
            o.OnCompleted();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            o.OnError(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The key is `return new CompositeDisposable(sub, new CancellationDisposable(cts))`. That's great! Thanks for a clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a method like this:

```
Task<Gizmo> GetGizmoAsync(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

You can turn that into an `IObservable<Gizmo>` where subscribing starts the `Task<Gizmo>` and unsubscribing cancels it by using the following.

```
IObservable<Gizmo> observable = Observable.FromAsync(
    cancellationToken => GetGizmoAsync(7, cancellationToken));

// Starts the task:
IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(...);

// Cancels the task if it is still running:
subscription.Dispose();
```