# Rx and tasks - cancel running task when new task is spawned?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an user interaction scenario I'd like to handle with Rx.

The scenario is similar to the canonical "when user stops typing, do some work" (usually, search for what the user has typed so far) (1) - but I also need to :

- (2) only get the **latest** of the results of "do some work" units (see below)
- (3) when a new unit of work starts, **cancel** any work in progress (in my case it's CPU intensive)

For (1) I use an `IObservable` for the user events, throttled with `.Throttle()` to only trigger on pauses between events ("user stops typing").

From that, i `.Select(_ => CreateMyTask(...).ToObservable())`.

This gives me an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` where each of the inner observables wraps a single task.

To get (2) I finally apply `.Switch()` to only get the results from the newest unit of work.

What about (3) - cancel pending tasks ?

If I understand correctly, whenever there's a new inner `IObservable<T>`, the `.Switch()` method subscribes to it and *unsubscribes* from the previous one(s), causing them to `Dispose()`.
Maybe that can be somehow wired to trigger the task to cancel?

Answer (score 14):

You can just use `Observable.FromAsync` which will generate tokens that are cancelled when the observer unsubcribes:

```
input.Throttle(...)
     .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(token => CreateMyTask(..., token)))
     .Switch()
     .Subscribe(...);
```

This will generate a new token for each unit of work and cancel it every time `Switch` switches to the new one.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this Factory method. It seems to be far preferable to the `ToObservable()` operator due to its cancellation support.

Comment: yeah I only discovered it a few weeks ago.  The bane of Rx is the lack of strong documentation.

Comment: @Brandon Lee's ebook *is* the documentation :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to work with Tasks?

If you're happy to work purely with Observables then you can do this nicely yourself.

Try doing something like this:

```
var query =
    Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        var cancelling = false;
        var cancel = Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            cancelling = true;
        });
        var subscription = Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10); //1000 ms in total
                if (cancelling)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled on {0}", i);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            return 42;
        }).Subscribe(o);
        return new CompositeDisposable(cancel, subscription);
    });
```

This observable is doing some hard work in the for loop with the `Thread.Sleep(10);`, but when the observable is disposed the loop is exited and the intensive CPU work ceases. Then you can use the standard Rx `Dispose` with the `Switch` to cancel the in progress work.

If you'd like that bundled up in a method, then try this:

```
public static IObservable<T> Start<T>(Func<Func<bool>, T> work)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var cancelling = false;
        var cancel = Disposable
            .Create(() => cancelling = true);
        var subscription = Observable
            .Start(() => work(() => cancelling))
            .Subscribe(o);
        return new CompositeDisposable(cancel, subscription);
    });
}
```

And then call it with a function like this:

```
Func<Func<bool>, int> work = cancelling =>
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10); //1000 ms in total
        if (cancelling())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled on {0}", i);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    return 42;
};
```

Here's my code that proved this worked:

```
var disposable =
    ObservableEx
        .Start(work)
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

Thread.Sleep(500);
disposable.Dispose();
```

I got "Cancelled on 50" (sometime "Cancelled on 51") as my output.

Comment: No, I don't have a requirement to use Task. It just felt natural to encapsulate the processing-intensive action in one. I'll take a good look at your solution :)

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu - To be honest I can see what the TPL has going for it, but I have always found that my solutions using Rx are always much neater and far more expressive. I try to avoid TPL in favour of Rx.

Comment: If you are embracing Rx, your proposed `Start` method could be made easier to understand as `Start(Func<CancellationToken, T> work)` and use a `CancellationDisposable` to generate the token instead of a custom disposable.  Or, if you *really* embrace Rx: `Start(Func<IObservable<Unit>, T> work)` where your `Start` method gives it an `AsyncSubject` that it signals cancellation when the subscription is disposed.  The `Func<bool>` just feels clunky and not in the spirit of Rx.

Comment: @Brandon - I take your point, but there are already Rx methods that take `Func<bool>` - `DoWhile` & `While`. In this case the `Func<bool> is appropriate as we need a direct way to break the execution within the generating function. Most of the the rest of the Rx operators are atomic - you can't interrupt the functions. That's my thinking at least.

Comment: While I up-voted the other answer, I do agree that each time I try to use Task/TPL I end up finding a far better (testable/composable/cancellable/readable) solution in Rx.

Comment: @LeeCampbell I agree, but we are finding in our code base that Rx has provided enough interfaces to TPL that we can easily switch between TPL and Rx to match the need of whatever bit we are coding.  I'm constantly impressed by the thought that has gone into Rx.