# How do I make an asynchronous HTTP request with RxNET?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Currently I'm using await inside an Observable.Create(). ExecuteRequestAsync is a wrapper class to call [HttpClient.GetAsync Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
    public IObservable<IList<ExampleResponseModel>> ListExamplesRx()
    {
        return Observable.Create<IList<ExampleResponseModel>>(
            o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var url = string.Format(Routes.Examples.List);
                    IList<ExampleResponseModel> exampleResponse = await ExecuteRequestAsync<IList<ExampleResponseModel>>(url, HttpMethod.Get);
                    o.OnNext(exampleResponse);
                    o.OnCompleted();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    o.OnError(e);
                }
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }
        );
    }
```

Is this the best practice? Is there a more appropriate rx solution?

Comment: As a general rule, whenever you have `return Disposable.Empty;` in a `.Create` then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: would removing `Disposable.Empty` correct the issue?  What should be returned in a situation like the above: `Observable.Create`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task<T>.ToObservable()` does what you're looking for:

```
public IObservable<IList<ExampleResponseModel>> ListExamplesRx()
{
    var url = string.Format(Routes.Examples.List);
    return ExecuteRequestAsync<IList<ExampleResponseModel>>(url, HttpMethod.Get)
        .ToObservable();
}
```

If you want a cold observable (ie. deferred execution) you can wrap the above in `Observable.Defer`.

If you need to support cancellation, see [How to create IObservable from Task such that unsubscribing cancels the task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487106/3603)

Comment: The other option, which may be better, is `return Observable.FromAsync(() => ExecuteRequestAsync<IList<ExampleResponseModel>>(url, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get));`. That should automatically do the deferred execution.

Comment: @Enigmativity The issue I have with that solution is that the HTTP request will be sent each time there is a subscriber. What if I want it to only be sent once on the first subscription and have the response remembered for future subscribers?

Comment: @void.pointer - You'd have to play around with `Replay` or `Multicast`.